# Which Object Oriented languages generate assembly directly (no intermediate representation)?

Tags: c++, assembly

I know that there is C++ which directly generates Assembly . But which more java like languages do that too?

Comment: What makes a language "more Java like" for you? And have you heard about gcj, a compiler that compiles Java directly to machine code?

Comment: Just about ***all*** compilers generate some kind of (internal) intermediate representation. And many big C++ compilers use their intermediate representation to generate machine-code directly without going through the assembly-step.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Languages do not generate assembly.  Compilers generate assembly.  C is an example of a language which is traditionally compiled to assembly, but there are some interpreters for it too (GDB being the most famous but incomplete).

Clang is an example of a compiler which accepts many input languages like C and C++, and while it does produce assembly code, it also uses an [intermediate representation](https://llvm.org/docs/LangRef.html).

Perhaps what you are asking here is which languages do not rely on a virtual machine or bytecode interpreter.  And that list is huge, because it includes every language for which a "traditional" compiler front-end has been written.  For example Python has Cython, which with some limitations lets you compile Python code as you would C or C++.

Wikipedia has a page about compiled languages with a long list here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compiled_language#Languages

Among those, some which may be relevant to your question as being "more Java like" could be Pascal, Go, and Ada.  They do not look like Java in terms of syntax, but they are less "bare metal" than C++.